# Is n log n = O(n) and is n log n = Omega(n)

Tags: loops, big-o, computer-science, complexity-theory

Hey guys i have been asked the above 2 questions with an explanation as to why. I'm quite confused, i know that the time it takes for an O(nlogn) algorithm to run grows faster then a linear O(n) algorithm but not quite sure the answer to these.
I'm fairly sure that n log n is not equivalent to O(n) but im not quite sure how to explain it. (i don't think we need to do an exact proof)

Comment: please use https://cs.stackexchange.com/  for this question. The easiest way to show that kind of relation is to draw both of the graphs on 2d plane. Then you see automatically if its upper or lower bound.

Comment: If your question is not about the .net implementation, consider removing the language specific tags.

Comment: Test equations with real numbers.    Suppose O(n) is 1,2,3,4,... to infinitiy.  So it is one times n.  If you look at left side of equation n log n it will be larger when log n is greater than one and smaller when log n is less than one.

Comment: Both are false because they're incorrect and don't make sense at all. (apples and oranges) on the left side you have pure functions on the right complexity, you can't go from one to another without a context of an algorithm.  If you would formulate `O(n*logn) = O(n)` then it would be false but at least it would make sense.

Comment: @Yoda: You've misunderstood the term "complexity". O(n) is a set of functions. When we say that the time complexity of a given algorithm is in O(n), this means that its time complexity is a function, such as 3n+20, that is an element of O(n). (You're right that it's not *quite* well-formed to write "f(n) = O(n)" -- strictly speaking, it should be "f(n) ∈ O(n)" -- but it's very common to use "=" for this, and doesn't usually cause any confusion.)

Comment: @ruakh No, I haven't misunderstood the term, it's obvious to me. It's all about asymptotic rate of growth.

Comment: @Yoda: Just because something seems "obvious" to you, that doesn't mean it's actually *correct*. The term "complexity" does *not* refer to asymptotic rates of growth; rather, it's just that we usually find it more useful and convenient to characterize complexity asymptotically than by computing it precisely.

Comment: @ruakh It is correct. Exact number of dominating operation execution is usually useless beside academic disputes. The  reason why we even calculate it is to give us an idea of speed that number of operations increases basing on size of increase of size of input data. This is why we just calculate dominating operation execution not the rest of trash around.

Comment: @Yoda: I'm not sure what the point of your last comment is. Remember, my only objection was to your use of the term "complexity" to mean "asymptotic rate of growth"; these are distinct concepts, and asymptotic rates of growth are useful in *many* situations -- *not* just when discussing the complexity of an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Claim: `n*log(n)` is not `O(n)`
Proof: the proof is by contradiction. Suppose that `n*log(n)` were `O(n)`. Then by the definition of `O` there must exist constants `n0` and `c` such that for all `n > n0`, `n*log(n) <= c * n`. Dividing both sides by `n` gives `log(n) <= c`. However, there is no constant `c` such that `log(n) <= c` for all `n > n0`; consider the sequence `n = 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, …, 2^k, …` This is a contradiction; so, the supposition was incorrect. In other words, `n*log(n)` cannot be `O(n)`.

Claim: `n*log(n)` is `Omega(n)`
Proof: the proof is direct. Choose `n0 = 1` and `c = 1`. Then `n*log(n) >= n = 1*n = c*n`, as required.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer:**

With ignoring some details you can say that f(n) = O(g(n)) means f(n) <= g(n) (not an actual inequality but just in terms of growth). Also, you can say that f(n)=Omega(g(n)) means f(n) >= g(n). (We can extend this to Theta, little o and little omega as well).

So basically, if you have an intuition that nlogn is a bigger function than n, then you can say: n log n = Omega(n) or equivalently n = O(n log n). But not the other way around.

Therefore, nlogn=O(n) is a wrong statement.

**Sophisticated answer:**

If you want to prove that f(n)=O(g(n)), then you need to find certain constants that satisfy the Big-O definition. You can look it up but I'm not gonna get into the details of that.

However, if you want to prove that f(n) is not in O(g(n)), then simply said you want to prove that f(n) <= g(n) is a wrong statement. As a result, it should be the case that f(n) > g(n). Now, you can express the **strictly larger (smaller)** comparison as little-o or little-omega. So, to prove that f(n) is not in O(g(n)) you should actually prove that f(n) > g(n) which translates to f(n) = little-omega(g(n)). To prove little o and little omega relationships you have to use limits.

A very good reference to learn about these formal proofs in details is "Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition" by Cormen.

Answer (score -1):

`n logn` is not `O(n)` because it increases faster than `n` meaning that `n` is not an upper bound for it.

On the other hand `n log n` is `Ω(n)` because `n` is a lower bound for it. The definition of `Ω` is that `for f(n)=Ω(g(n)) means that for any c there exists an n such that 0<=cg(n)<=f(n)`.